# get all images from the wordpress media library with link to the post they are associated with

Tags: wordpress, image

I'm trying to get all the images from the wordpress media library with link to the post they are associated with.

I'm using this code, I get all the images, but the link is the link to the URL of the image, not the post they are associated with.

```
<?php

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'post_status' => null,
    'post_parent' => null, // any parent
    ); 
$attachments = get_posts($args);
if ($attachments) {
    foreach ($attachments as $post) {
        setup_postdata($post);
        the_attachment_link($post->ID, false);
    }
}

?>
```

using this code I get all the images, but without the link.

```
    <?php $wpb_all_query =

        new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_status' => 'inherit', 'posts_per_page' => -1)); ?>

    <?php if ($wpb_all_query->have_posts()) : ?>

        <?php while ($wpb_all_query->have_posts()) : $wpb_all_query->the_post(); ?>
            <?php echo get_image_tag(get_the_ID(), '', '', 'none', 'medium'); ?>
        <?php endwhile; ?>

    <?php endif; ?>
```

can anybody help me with this ?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe attachments use `post_parent` as the "link".  So you could do something like this:

```
foreach ($attachments as $attachment) {
    setup_postdata($post);
    $linked_post_id = $attachment->post_parent;

    // do something w/ $linked_post_id
}
```